# "Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized"

Tags: c#

[image]

I have just started my learning experience with c# and this problem has been teasing me. Please help :)

Comment: What do you want to do with this line of code ?

Comment: Constructive criticism is appreciated.

Comment: @mybirthname its just a test, to like try what i have learned. as you can see its just some kind of age restriction. just practicing "if" and "else" and the basic concepts :)

Comment: @mybirthname oh you mean the line... im dumb.. i wanna make the user input their age but i cant get it to work as you can see

Comment: Just use `var userAge = Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: You've declared a variable (without specifying the data type or initial value) and then you've it set it to itself. All you need is `var userAge = Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: First ConsoleReadLine() will return string. So you need to parse the value from console using int.Parse or int.TryParse. Your definition of userAge should be var userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: Thanks for the answers. i tried what @Lee told me to do before asking this question but its works now.. thanks folks.

Comment: For future reference, please paste code as text instead of screenshots (adding any error messages as comments where they appear)

Comment: Also you probably want that line to go after the following `Console.WriteLine` on the next line. At the moment the program will wait for the users input before displaying the prompt.

Comment: duly noted. @DStanley

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GzW2V now i get this. @Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `int.TryParse` to be safe, otherwise a wrong input would throw an error.

```
string userAgeInput = Console.Readline();
int userAge = 0;

if (!int.TryParse(userAgeInput, out userAge))
    Console.WriteLine("Please input a valid age!");
```

Now you can compare `userAge`.

```
if (userAge >= 18)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the image you attached, the error is on line 16. You wrote:

`var userAge = userAge = Console.ReadLine();`

It should be:

`var userAge = Console.ReadLine();`

As people have rightly pointed out in the comments, `Console.ReadLine()` will return something of type `string`. But in your if statements, you're trying to compare it to something of type `int` (e.g. `if (userAge >= 18)`. You'll need to manually convert `userAge` to an `int` like so:

`if (int.Parse(userAge) >= 18)`

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GzW2V i am currently getting this error now.

Answer (score 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/enp4O.jpg

Thanks to everyone! Made my first finished simple Console application on my first day of learning any programming language in the "C family"

Comment: Please do not paste image but text + do not thanks people by creating a non answer

Answer (score 0):

Notice the squiggly line under the userAge in "`var userAge = userAge = Console`..." ?

No need for the second userAge.

Comment: imgur.com/a/GzW2V i am currently getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

On your line:

```
var userAge = userAge = Console.Readline();
```

You are setting the new variable `userAge` to be equal to a previously defined `userAge` which has not been defined yet

Comment: Ideally userage should be a number so after you read from console,the input will be type string. So convert it to int using int.parse      var userAge = int.Parse(Console.Readline());        Again, you have to bear mind that if user doesnt enter a number this will throw an exception. So you can instead use int.tryparse. You should google out the syntax for this. As a side note, If you are new to programming, i would suggest to enroll in a free online C# course from sites like microsoft virtual academy or coursera

Comment: imgur.com/a/GzW2V i am currently getting this error.

Comment: `Console.Readline()` returns type `string`. So currently userAge is a string. You need to use `int.Parse` to convert the contents of userAge to an integer, this will need to be assigned to another variable for use. You may also need to do some error handling if anything other than a number is entered